# Calculate co-occurrence matrix in android?

Tags: java, android, opencv

i'm working on **android** project  **credit card reader**.

First,i removed background by applying **DCT** (desecrate cosine transform)
and **high pass filter**. Now i  need to calculate **co-occurrence**
for **Mat image** then use the result  to calculate **homogeneity and
contrast**  .

I did not find co-occurrence function for android, i have no experience in image processing and now i'm stuck:( so anyone
can help please.

Comment: What is the "Mat image"? [Co-occurence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_matrix) seems just to be a double sum. You could just calculate it maybe?

Comment: @Trilarion Mat is Matrix of image